# SystemTimeToFileTime exact replacement in linux

Tags: c, linux, time

Tried to find a complete analog to the function SystemTimeToFileTime, but cannot find it.

I have all the SYSTEMTIME and FILETIME structures with correctly working SYSTEMTIME on linux for the date difference function:

```
int64_t Delta2(const SYSTEMTIME st1, const SYSTEMTIME st2) { 

    union timeunion { FILETIME fileTime; ULARGE_INTEGER ul; } ;
    timeunion ft1;
    timeunion ft2;
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st1, &ft1.fileTime);
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st2, &ft2.fileTime);

    return ft2.ul.QuadPart - ft1.ul.QuadPart; 
}
```

Anybody knows an exact replacement of the `SystemTimeToFileTime` function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you consult the sources of the WINE project which will contain exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

A `FILETIME` is just a timestamp with 10 millisecond resolution, split into two 32-bit numbers. A POSIX timestamp (with second resolution) can simply be multiplied by 100 to get that.

To get from a `SYSTEMTIME` to a `FILETIME` you could create a `struct tm` with the relevant fields, and use `mktime` to create a `time_t`. Put that timestamp in a 64-bit integer, multiply 100 (to get 10 millisecond resolution) and add the `SYSTEMTIME` `wMilliseconds` field (divided by 10), and you have your `FILETIME`.

Comment: A small changes are required.  `FILETIME` is 100ns intervals since January 1, 1601, `mktime` converts to seconds from January 1, 1970 and  `SYSTEMTIME`  and `tm` also contains 1900 years of difference.

Comment: Ohh, and just noticed there is tm_gmtoff difference between Windows and Linux result.

Answer (score 0):

[`SYSTEMTIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Specifies a date and time, using individual members for the month, day, year, weekday, hour, minute, second, and millisecond. The time is either in coordinated universal time (UTC) or local time, depending on the function that is being called.

The nearest type would be [`struct tm`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/ctime), although it has no milliseconds.

[`FILETIME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724284%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> Contains a 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC).

You can use `struct timeval` (supports microseconds) or `struct timespec` (supports nanoseconds)

Not all filesystems support nanoseconds, `ext4` does, for example.

[`SystemTimeToFileTime`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724948%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You can use [`mktime`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/mktime) for this, although you will get only seconds since epoch (1970-01-01 00:00 UTC).

So, I would say an *exact* replacement is difficult, to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

Linux doesn't have  concept of "filetime" as such. Depending on exactly what you are doing, it may be better to use `difftime` (give the difference between two time_t in seconds as a floating point number), or use some more precise timestamps and convert that into a difference in 10ms intervals?

You can use `mktime` to convert a date/time value into a `time_t`.